# How To Handle IE Setup Popup in Selenium

Tags: selenium, alerts

how to handle IE set up in selenium click image for alert popup
[image]

Comment: Did you tried following capability set up to ignore this popup
`capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);`

Comment: I have tried all below listed but not working  capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability("allow-blocked-content", true);
capabilities.setCapability("allowBlockedContent", true);
capabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
capabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to accept the alert via selenium.  The following Java method should accept the alert and let you move on with your life.

```
public void checkAlert() 
{
    try 
    {
        // Wait for the alert to show
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //exception handling
    }
}
```

You'll want to add `import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;` to your imports too.