# How to handle below Internet Explorer popup "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" through Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, internet-explorer, onbeforeunload

How to Handle below IE Popup in Selenium

[image]

Comment: you can use https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/robot-class-java-awt/ robot class for handling this popup - Refer that link for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Internet Explorer* popup with text as **Are you sure you want to leave this page?** is the result of **`WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload`**

---

### onbeforeunload

The [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) property of the [WindowEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers) mixin is the [EventHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) for processing [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) events. These events fire when a window is about to [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) its resources. At this point, the document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

---

### Solution

There are different strategies available to handle this *popup*. However, as a **Cross Browser** solution, you can disable this dialog invoking the `executeScript()` to set `window.onbeforeunload` as **`function() {};`** and you can use the following solution:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};");
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to disable a “Reload site? Changes you made may not be saved” popup for (python) selenium tests in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587025/how-to-disable-a-reload-site-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-popup-for-pyt/55590017#55590017)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to accept the alert via selenium.  Not sure what language you're using but the following Java method should accept the alert and let you move on with your life.

```
public void checkAlert() 
{
    try 
    {
        // Wait for the alert to show
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //exception handling
    }
}
```

You'll want to add `import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;` to your imports (again if you're using Java)

Comment: Can you please give me solution for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179189/how-to-handle-ie-setup-popup-in-selenium

Comment: It would be the same thing right? Just switch to the alert and accept it. I can add an answer on there if you like.

Answer (score 0):

For java, you can usee the following code,

```
    // Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path_to_chromedriver");

    // Create ChromeOptions instance
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    // Disable pop-ups
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");

    // Create WebDriver instance
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    // Rest of your code...
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks.