# How to understand that a page has an alert or not with use of Selenium in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, popup, alert

There are many solutions for interaction with `alerts` in web pages using `Selenium` in `Python`. But, I want a solution to find that the page has an `alert` or no. Use of `Try & except` is very bad solution in my case. So, don't present that. I want just a simple `if & else` solution. 
This is my solution:

```
if driver.switch_to_alert()
  alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
  alert.accept()
else:
  print('hello')

NoAlertPresentException: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: There is no way other than `try except`. Why is it so bad?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python And do you mean just window.alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
driver.executeScript("window.alert = () => window.alertHappened = true")
// some code here that may cause alert
alert_happened = driver.executeScript("return !!window.alertHappened")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you automate the *Regression Testcases* you are always aware that where there is an **alert** on the webpage. As per the current implementation to switch to an *Alert* you need to use:

- [`switch_to.alert()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) as follows:

  ```
  selenium.webdriver.common.alert 
  driver.switch_to.alert().accept()
  ```
- As per best practices you should always induce *WebDriverWait* for the [`alert_is_present()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.alert_is_present) while switching to an **Alert** as follows:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # other lines of code
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present).accept()
  ```
- To validate that a page has an *Alert* or not the ideal approach would be to wrap up the *Alert handling code block* in a `try-catch{}` block as follows:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present).accept()
      print("Alert accepted")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("No Alert was present")
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussion in:

- [How to read the text from the alert box using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074558/how-to-read-the-text-from-the-alert-box-using-python-selenium/47075168#47075168)
- [Why switching to alert through selenium is not stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839355/why-switching-to-alert-through-selenium-is-not-stable/48839525#48839525)

---

### Outro

There may be some cases when you may need to interact with elements those cannot be inspected through css/xpath within google-chrome-devtools and you will find a detailed discussion in [How to interact with elements those cannot be inspected through css/xpath within google-chrome-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556644/how-to-interact-with-elements-those-cannot-be-inspected-through-css-xpath-within/55566851#55566851)