# How to disable a "Reload site? Changes you made may not be saved" popup for (python) selenium tests in chrome?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I am running automated (python) selenium tests on a chrome browser, and sometimes when a page is reloaded a popup appears on the screeen:

[image]

Is it possible to configure the chrome selenium browser in such a way, that this popup **does not appear**? If so, how to do that? Or are there other ways to supress this popup? Or to accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This popup with text as **Reload site? Changes you made may not be saved** is the implementation of **`onbeforeunload`** property of [WindowEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers)

---

### onbeforeunload

The [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) property of the [WindowEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers) mixin is the [EventHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) for processing [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) events. These events fire when a window is about to [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) its resources. At this point, the document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

---

### Solution

There are different strategies available to handle this *popup*.

- **Chrome** solution: Using `--disable-popup-blocking` through *ChromeOptions()*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=/path/to/chromedriver')
  ```
- **Firefox** solution: Using `dom.disable_beforeunload` through *FirefoxProfile()*:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
  profile.set_preference("dom.disable_beforeunload", True)
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile)
  ```
- **Cross Browser** solution: As a *Cross Browser* solution, you can disable this dialog invoking the `executeScript()` to set *window.onbeforeunload* as `function() {};` and you can use the following solution:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};")
  ```
- **JQuery** based solution:

  ```
  $I->executeJS( "window.onbeforeunload = null" );
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to handle below Internet Explorer popup “Are you sure you want to leave this page?” through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293394/how-to-handle-below-internet-explorer-popup-are-you-sure-you-want-to-leave-this/55295166#55295166)

Comment: I just realized I have this flag `--disable-popup-blocking` already for Chrome. However, it does not seem to work properly. I still get the popup from time to time (repeating the exact same webpage).

Comment: when do I have to execute the script? Just one time after I created the driver? Each time for a new page?

Comment: Popup still appears sometimes.

Comment: Please expand this to include where to find ChromeOptions(); or where / how to implement the jQuery solution? Where would I put the jQuery soluion? $I is not defined.

Comment: As of today, the Chrome's solution does not seem to have any influence in avoiding the appearance of alert popups.

Answer (score 4):

I know this doesn't answer the suppression part of the question, but..

Try this piece of code for accepting the popup:

`driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();`

Comment: Yes I guess I will use this suggestion. But the alert pops up only sometimes.

Comment: You could try adding "Try Except" block to try to switch to the alert window

Answer (score 0):

For java, you can usee the following code,

```
// Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path_to_chromedriver");

// Create ChromeOptions instance
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// Disable pop-ups
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");

// Create WebDriver instance
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Rest of your code...
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.