# How to accept "This action cannot be undone. Are you sure you want to delete this wishlist" popup using Selenium and Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onbeforeunload

I'm in need of clicking the first button of a browser notification, which appears after clicking on a button "Delete Wishlist".
This button is as below;

```
  <a href="/account/wishlistupdate?mainAction=delete&amp;wishlistId=2547474" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('This action cannot be undone. Are you sure you want to delete this wishlist?')" style="" xpath="1">Delete wishlist</a>
```

This button click opens a browser notification.

[image]

I have tried alert.accept(), but doesn't work for me.

```
 public HomePage editWishlist(){
    click(edit_button);    //     By edit_button = By.xpath("//div[@class='btn-edit-text']");

    click(deleteWishlist_button); //    By deleteWishlist_button = By.linkText("Delete wishlist");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("got interrupted!");
    }

    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();

    return this;
}
```

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a `Javascript Confirmation Alert` and you can accept it by `switching` to it and then `accepting` it:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Similarly to click on `cancel` you can call method `dismiss()`

Comment: maybe you need to wait for it to load before actually executing this code? try `Thread.sleep(1000);` if it works then you can apply selenium waits

Comment: any exception trace?

Comment: No, it doesn't fail. It passes, but the functionality after clicking on "Ok" button is not applied.

Comment: I just created a script for same website to delete from wishlist and it seems to work

Comment: can you share code? maybe you are doing something wrong

Comment: please add it in question with proper formatting, its hard to read this way

Answer (score 0):

This popup with text as

```
This action cannot be undone. Are you sure you want to delete this wishlist?
```

...is the implementation of `onbeforeunload` property of [WindowEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers).

---

### onbeforeunload

The [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) property of the [WindowEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers) mixin is the [EventHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) for processing [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) events. These events fire when a window is about to [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) its resources. At this point, the document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

---

### Solution

A *Cross Browser* solution would be to disable this dialog invoking the `executeScript()` setting *window.onbeforeunload* as `function() {};` and you can use the following solution:

```
    driver.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};")
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to disable a “Reload site? Changes you made may not be saved” popup for (python) selenium tests in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587025/how-to-disable-a-reload-site-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-popup-for-pyt/55590017#55590017)