# Selenium, python, chrome driver, outlook automation: outlook.office365.com wants to Open email links

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, outlook, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing automation of downloading email from outlook.com, 
 I'm using selenium with python and chrome driver.

Everything is working as expected, I'm unable to disable this prompt 
 "outlook.office365.com wants to Open email links". 
 Here's the screen-snip of the same, how to disable it or stop from popping?

[image: outlook.office365.com wants to Open email links].

This pops-up 7/10 times, because of this whole automation get affected.

I tried almost everything to resolve it, no solution. Here's the snippet for the same:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
prefs = {'credentials_enable_service': False,
         'profile.password_manager_enabled': False,
         'profile.default_content_setting_values.popups': False,
         'profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications': False,
         'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1,
         'profile.default_content_setting_values': {"handlers": False},
         'download.default_directory': attachment_download_directory}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.set_window_size(960, 800)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587025/how-to-disable-a-reload-site-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-popup-for-pyt

Comment: `options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')` already added in my snippet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable a "Reload site? Changes you made may not be saved" popup for (python) selenium tests in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587025/how-to-disable-a-reload-site-changes-you-made-may-not-be-saved-popup-for-pyt)

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for.